# SelendroidDriver cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, selenium, webdriver, selendroid

**SelendroidDriver cannot be resolved to a type.** I am facing this problem in selendroid, when i am trying to crate a selendroid driver object using  **WebDriver driver = new SelendroidDriver(capa);**.
I have added both **selendroid-standalone-0.12.0-with-dependencies** and **selendroid-client-0.4.2-sources** jars to build path.Below is the code:

public class TestSelendroid {

```
@Test
public void runSelendroidTest() throws Exception {

    SelendroidCapabilities capa = new SelendroidCapabilities("io.selendroid.testapp:0.12.0");

    capa.setPlatformVersion(DeviceTargetPlatform.ANDROID10);

    capa.setEmulator(true);

    WebDriver driver = new SelendroidDriver(capa);

    WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.id("my_text_field"));
    Assert.assertEquals("true", inputField.getAttribute("enabled"));
    inputField.sendKeys("Selendroid");
    Assert.assertEquals("Selendroid", inputField.getText());

    driver.quit();

}

}
```

And this is the status of selendroid server on cmd:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

D:\Selendroid Jar>java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.12.0-with-dependencies.jar -
app selendroid-test-app-0.12.0.apk
################# Selendroid #################
################# Configuration in use #################
io.selendroid.SelendroidConfiguration@3be5d207[
  port=4444
  timeoutEmulatorStart=300000
  supportedApps=[selendroid-test-app-0.12.0.apk]
  verbose=false
  emulatorPort=5560
  deviceScreenshot=false
  selendroidServerPort=8080
  keystore=<null>
  keystorePassword=<null>
  keystoreAlias=<null>
  emulatorOptions=<null>
  registrationUrl=<null>
  proxy=<null>
  serverHost=<null>
  keepAdbAlive=false
  noWebViewApp=false
  noClearData=false
  sessionTimeoutSeconds=1800
  forceReinstall=false
  logLevel=ERROR
  deviceLog=true
  serverStartTimeout=20000
  printHelp=false
]
Jan 09, 2015 12:03:42 PM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher launchServer
INFO: Starting selendroid-server port 4444
Jan 09, 2015 12:03:42 PM io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver i
nitApplicationsUnderTest
SEVERE: Ignoring app because it was not found: D:\Selendroid Jar\selendroid-test
-app-0.12.0.apk
Jan 09, 2015 12:03:42 PM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe remo
ve C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver6507564983638345758.apk META-I
NF/MANIFEST.MF
Jan 09, 2015 12:03:42 PM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe remo
ve C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver6507564983638345758.apk META-I
NF/CERT.RSA
Jan 09, 2015 12:03:42 PM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe remo
ve C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver6507564983638345758.apk META-I
NF/CERT.SF
Jan 09, 2015 12:03:43 PM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe remo
ve C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver6507564983638345758.apk META-I
NF/ANDROIDD.SF
Jan 09, 2015 12:03:43 PM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe remo
ve C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver6507564983638345758.apk META-I
NF/ANDROIDD.RSA
Jan 09, 2015 12:03:43 PM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe remo
ve C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver6507564983638345758.apk META-I
NF/NDKEYSTO.SF
Jan 09, 2015 12:03:43 PM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe remo
ve C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver6507564983638345758.apk META-I
NF/NDKEYSTO.RSA
Jan 09, 2015 12:03:43 PM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\jarsigner.exe -sigalg MD
5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\resigned-an
droid-driver6507564983638345758.apk -storepass android -keystore C:\Users\user\.
android\debug.keystore C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver6507564983
638345758.apk androiddebugkey
Jan 09, 2015 12:03:43 PM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher launchServer
SEVERE: Error occurred while building server: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellComm
andException: An error occured while executing shell command: C:\Program Files\J
ava\jre7\bin\jarsigner.exe -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar C:\User
s\user\AppData\Local\Temp\resigned-android-driver6507564983638345758.apk -storep
ass android -keystore C:\Users\user\.android\debug.keystore C:\Users\user\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\android-driver6507564983638345758.apk androiddebugkey
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An e
rror occured while executing shell command: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\jarsi
gner.exe -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar C:\Users\user\AppData\Loc
al\Temp\resigned-android-driver6507564983638345758.apk -storepass android -keyst
ore C:\Users\user\.android\debug.keystore C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\andro
id-driver6507564983638345758.apk androiddebugkey
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplication
sUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:146)
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<init>(Selendro
idStandaloneDriver.java:84)
        at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidS
erver(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:61)
        at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(SelendroidStan
daloneServer.java:50)
        at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java
:64)
        at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.java:112)
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured whil
e executing shell command: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\jarsigner.exe -sigalg
MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\resigned-
android-driver6507564983638345758.apk -storepass android -keystore C:\Users\user
\.android\debug.keystore C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver65075649
83638345758.apk androiddebugkey
        at io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
        at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.signTestServer(Selendro
idServerBuilder.java:294)
        at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(SelendroidSer
verBuilder.java:153)
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplication
sUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:142)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException:
        ... 9 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: io.selendroid.exceptions.
ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: C:\Progra
m Files\Java\jre7\bin\jarsigner.exe -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedja
r C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\resigned-android-driver6507564983638345758.ap
k -storepass android -keystore C:\Users\user\.android\debug.keystore C:\Users\us
er\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver6507564983638345758.apk androiddebugkey
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplication
sUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:146)
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<init>(Selendro
idStandaloneDriver.java:84)
        at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidS
erver(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:61)
        at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(SelendroidStan
daloneServer.java:50)
        at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java
:64)
        at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.java:112)
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured whil
e executing shell command: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\jarsigner.exe -sigalg
MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\resigned-
android-driver6507564983638345758.apk -storepass android -keystore C:\Users\user
\.android\debug.keystore C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver65075649
83638345758.apk androiddebugkey
        at io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
        at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.signTestServer(Selendro
idServerBuilder.java:294)
        at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(SelendroidSer
verBuilder.java:153)
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplication
sUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:142)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException:
        ... 9 more

D:\Selendroid Jar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following steps to solve your issue :

1 - Add selendroid-client-0.10.0 [Remove your selendroid-client-0.4.2-sources]

2 - Add selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0

After add above JARS , save your program and then check

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but now i have an other issue.Error "Could not connect to the server.Possible causes are invalid address..." is showing when i try to run the code.Can u help me out from this.

Comment: Can you please share you code? update your question with code.

Comment: Have you put your APK in same folder of selendroid JAR?

Comment: -I have tried both selendroid jar and .apk in same folder and jar and .apk in different folders. Should they both in same folder or different?

Comment: Put both in same folder. after run your command from cmd , please accesss this URL [http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status] in browser and tell me what you getting in browser.

Comment: Cannot connect to [localhost:4444/wd/hub/status], showing this web page is not available.

Comment: remove this apk: selendroid-test-app-0.12.0.apk  and put your and then do command line with your APK name..

Comment: Same result, cannot connect to localhost.:(

Comment: then you are missing something in your selendroid config.

Comment: make your you are putting your apk in same folder of selendroid.

Comment: then call it using command line :  java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.12.0-with-dependencies.jar -app yourAPKname.apk

Comment: I have selendroid-standalone and my .apk in the same folder.I have tried 3 versions(2.41, 2.42 & 2.44) of selenim and the code mentioned in question, the cmd status is also mentioned.Still facing the same.:(((

Comment: As per your updated question command line error says it is not getting APK. when you run command line after that does it generates "Resigned APK? in same folder?

Comment: No it doesn't generate "Resigned APK". That is the error i am facing.I have tried everything to resolve it but still facing it. Can you help me out?

Comment: it must generate "Resigned APK". that is first proof that your command line for selendroid is working.